# Get function reference from mssql TYPES object using string

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, typescript

Node.js / mssql / typescript

I'm trying to build a set of input parameters dynamically and add them to a prepared statement.
With the code below, the error I get is:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type '{ VarChar:
> ISqlTypeFactoryWithLength; NVarChar: ISqlTypeFactoryWithLength; Text:
> ISqlTypeFactoryWithNoParams; ... 29 more ...; Variant:
> ISqlTypeFactoryWithNoParams; }'.

```
import { TYPES, PreparedStatement } from 'mssql'
...
const ps = new PreparedStatement(pool);
parameters.forEach((param: IParam) =>{
  let t1 = TYPES[param.dataType]; // ** This doesn't work **
  ps.input(param.name, t1);
  values[param.name] = param.value;
});
...


export interface IParam {
  name: string;
  dataType: string;
  length: number;
  value?: string;
}
```

Oddly (to me anyway) I can use this code without issue.

```
  let t1 = TYPES['VarChar'];      // This does work
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine your `parameters` array looks like:

```ts
const parameters: IParam[] = [
    {
        name: "abc",
        dataType: "not_a_valid_data_type",
        length: 4
    }
]
```

According to the `IParam` interface you've defined, this is a valid input. However, `"not_a_valid_data_type"` doesn't exist as a key on the `TYPES` object. So if TypeScript allowed you to do this, the runtime code would end up being:

```ts
let t1 = TYPES["not_a_valid_data_type"];
```

Which would make the value of `t1` be `undefined`.

In order to use your `dataType` field as an index, you need to limit it to only be the set of keys on the `TYPES` object:

```ts
type DataType = keyof typeof TYPES; // "VarChar" | "NVarChar" | "Text" | ...

export interface IParam {
  name: string;
  dataType: DataType;
  length: number;
  value?: string;
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgTQAoFEDKMC8MDeBYAKBmJgDUBDAJwGEALKgLlxigE8AHAUyYCIKb6lHjAC+AGkIkYAOX51GzNl16yq8oaIlEScTgA8oTHCw7cYPXQeEjJJAPR2YAOhecowJ4RsFCSzjAARcihyOFMsGABrTlYQADMTLnj4ZHQAbkJCAEswKE5KOPJgfwBJJCpyAFtcWzAqs2hKHIBzDO0AE2DQ0yYgkLCuNuIAG04wZqhaJjAAV0qAI3yhmAA3cmGZzgB+JkaWtu9CUEhYdgrKt3yIJjLzgG0AXQi722J8bSliOovech4tT4kTr9HrmOSCf6vT6jcaTJgADih4kIDzahDOlHqeUoECccRAlBQRVoAAoSRiqjdypjKgBKLAAPneIzcLAAjBFEKg0HcKZUnMDulxUV5aWifARjtAYDk1sMsu1qVirlT7k9sC8PjAHDIQAB3GCxGYwZqs-KUAkQGB62hjFiUVgtFggGAzCD+chgGVgUCUSicYCwQWJThQ5mAmDfMw8eaQrVSQUDaNgEBQAD65DTcoVacFab8cYjMBhEymMAALEiUUA)

Comment: Thank you very much for the description, as well as the solution. I kept reading other pages about that error, and I understood there was a potential for "not_a_valid_data_type".  I just didn't know how to type dataType so that it was acceptable. 

Based on your response I understand now that would also have worked to type dataType like this: `dataType: 'VarChar' | 'NVarChar' | 'Text' | ...`
My workaround was a really long switch statement. This is far more elegant. 
Much appreciated.